# error "data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))" en django :(

Tags: javascript, html, python, jquery, django

Me da este error "data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))" al querer cargar un json traído de un js con django. Es para un proyecto escolar :( El código recibe una foto tomada por el navegador y la guarda y el error aparece al recibir el post por parte del html Aquí el código del view del proyecto.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
import json
import base64
import os
import logging

from random import randint

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

def Inicio(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        image_url = data.get('image_url', '')

        # Guarda la imagen físicamente en la carpeta de medios
        guardar_imagen_fisicamente(image_url)

        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Imagen recibida y guardada con éxito.'})
    return render(request, 'plantilla1.html')

def guardar_imagen_fisicamente(image_url):
    # Decodifica la imagen base64
    image_data = image_url.split(",")[1]
    image_binary = base64.b64decode(image_data)

    # Guarda la imagen en la carpeta de medios
    ruta_carpeta = 'capturas'
    ruta_completa = os.path.join('media', ruta_carpeta, generar_nombre_imagen())
    ruta_completa = os.path.join("C:/myproject/myproject/", ruta_completa)

    with open(ruta_completa, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(image_binary)

def generar_nombre_imagen():
    n = randint(0,999999999)
    nombre_imagen = f"imagen_{n}.png"
    return nombre_imagen
```

Cosas como url y settings estan bien, ya esta revisado pero me da error en cuando quiero obtener la data, y es que me explota enter[image: es la imagen del error]
Inexperadamente si me toma la foto, es decir si hace lo que quiero que haga, es raro

aqui el html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Captura de Imagen</title>
    <!-- Agrega aquí tus enlaces a jQuery o a otras bibliotecas si es necesario -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="/Inicio/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div>
            <video id="camera-preview" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
            <button id="capture-btn">Capturar Imagen</button>
            <div id="image-url-container">URL de la imagen: </div>
        </div>
    </form>

<script>
    //var nombreImagen;  // Variable para almacenar el nombre de la imagen
    var imageURL;  // Variable para almacenar la URL de la imagen capturada

    // Acceder a la cámara y mostrar la vista previa
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
        .then(function (stream) {
            var video = document.getElementById('camera-preview');
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.play();
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.error('Error al acceder a la cámara:', err);
        });

    // Capturar la imagen y almacenar la URL
    var captureBtn = document.getElementById('capture-btn');
    captureBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var video = document.getElementById('camera-preview');
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
        canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        imageURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        document.getElementById('image-url-container').innerText = 'URL de la imagen: ' + imageURL;
        alert('Imagen capturada con éxito.');

        var csrfToken = document.cookie.match(/csrftoken=([^;]+)/)[1];
        // Obtener el token CSRF del formulario
        var csrfToken = document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value;
        // Realizar la solicitud POST incluyendo el token CSRF
        fetch('/Inicio/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ image_url: imageURL}),
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`La solicitud falló con estado: ${response.status}`);
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log('Respuesta del servidor:', data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Si se puede arreglar se lo agradecería mucho

Si alguien lo arregla se lo agradecería mucho, por favor y gracias

Comment: Añadió otra imagen con error. Mira al linea de código de "Inicio" functiona de la imagen, no hay 'decode('utf-8')' método. También, mostra el contenido de "body"